# Search Path network server sql with a Add Connection window form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How can I open the Add Connection window form through code to allow the administretor user to choose the network path of the sql server? Is it possible to do this in some way?
Thank you

Comment: You could use [Enumerating Instances of SQL Server (ADO.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enumerating-instances-of-sql-server) to get information to populate a combobox.

Comment: Grazie per tutto

Comment: È possibile poi  avere un elenco dei database di una istanza sql server?

Comment: [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2014), and please use English as this is an English-language site.